# PHP host without database drivers

Tags: php, database

My web host (bargainvault) has PHP 5 installed, but it does not have a ton of database drivers installed. I specifically need sqlite3, but they only have the sqlite driver installed. And no PDO.

So, my question is how can I bring support for my database to my application if there is no driver installed? I have looked at several database abstration layers, and they all seem to need those drivers installed.

Comment: @nikic - I dont understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. An abstraction layer is not a substitute for the underlying driver.
Your choices are:

1. become a good friend of the server admin and make him install PDO
2. find another host
3. make do with SQLite v. 2

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting supports mysql, and it is supported from mant abstraction layers.